# C# StreamReader read value of type

Tags: c#

I know when using a `StreamReader` I am able to use `ReadLine()` to return the whole line as a string, or even use `Read()` to return x amount of characters. However is there a way to read the next value of type?

In C++ you can do something like:

```
float x,y,z;
fileReader >> x >> y >> z;
```

To pipe the next three floating point values from the file stream into the variables.

I was just wondering if C# had a similar method to do this as reading a string and then decomposing it makes for un-necessary messy code.

Comment: look up the `seek` method or if you want to get all the values into a string[]  use the `File.ReadAllText` method then you can do all the forward seeking you need

Comment: @MethodMan thanks, I'll head over to MS docs now - It's not part of the `StreamReader` class is it?

Comment: @JoeyCiechanowicz thanks for pointing that out, I had searched but didn't stumble on anything.

Comment: why not do a msdn search yourself to findout.. :)